# loop in loop to calculate a sum of a "continuous product" sequence function in R

Tags: r, function, loops, package

I try to calculate the value for the following equation in R.

[image]

I have the dataset and the value for each corresponding F_x, F_{x+1}...

However, as both  `Q` and `s` have too many values, I am considering write a loop in loop. It's bit confused. As  a loop for `Q` seems conflicting as the loop for `s`

But if I write loop as below, seems like I need to by hand calculate Q 100 times to get all of the answer. Also my loop seems to be wrong...How can I fix this problem? Thank you so much

```
Y <- function(x,s, Q){
  n <- length(s-x)-1
  Q <- c(1:100)

    for(s in seq(1:n)){

     Y[s] <- sum(s*Q[s]*cumprod(Fx[1:s])) 
    }
return(Y)
}
```

Comment: Couple of examples with expected answer would help us verify our solutions. I am sure there is a better answer out there than 3 nested `for` loops.

Comment: Also, you keep overwriting `Y` in your loop. Are you only interested in its last value, or do you want all values in between as well? On top of that, I think you need `cumprod(Fx[1:s])` instead of `cumprod(Fx[s])`, since you want to multiply all values from Fx1 to Fxs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the code below reaches your objective

```
Y <- function(x,s) {
  Q <- 1:100
  S <- 1:(s-x)
  outer(Q,S,FUN = function(q,s) q * sum(c(1:s) * cumprod(Fx[1:s])))
}
```

---

`for` loop version

```
Y <- function(x,s) {
  nr <- 100
  nc <- s-x
  y <- matrix(nr*nc,nrow = nr)
  for (Q in 1:nr) {
    for (S in 1:nc) {
      y[Q,S] <- Q * sum(c(1:S) * cumprod(Fx[1:S]))
    }
  }
  y
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! Can we write in a for loop format?

Comment: Thank you for your time. One more issue. If instead of  ```QS*Fx```, if it is ```(2+Q)^(-S)*Fx``` how can I change this equation? I tried using ```(2+Q)^(-S)```, it works fine individually, but when I mix in loop, it turns an error as "unused argument (-c(1:s))"

Comment: @ScarlettZhao How do you use it in `for` loop? Could you show a piece of your code or better to create a new post with more details.